# Manage Database from Mainbundle with coredata

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have a read-only Database and want to use CoreData. But I would not copy it to the Documents Folder, because it is read-only.
Is there any way to use CoreData with a Database which is in the Mainbundle?

Comment: did you try `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error` with the option {NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption:@YES} ?

Comment: Why does location matter for readonly or readwrite option ? You could have readonly database wherever inside app ? Just dont write anything to the database